# Adjusting contrast of a color scale with ListDensityPlot

Tags: graphics, color, plotting

I am using ListDensityPlot to plot data of the form  {{x1,y1,z1},{x2,y2,z2}, …}.
It results in the plot shown below.  But I'd like to adjust the color scale contrast to better show the variations in the low-Z parts (in blue). Basically, I need more color variations for the low Z values (below ~30) and less color variations for larger values.

I've tried a log scale, but it does not show the contract sufficiently.
Thanks for the help.

Here is a simplified version of the code I am using:

```
colorbar[{min_, max_}, colorFunction_: Automatic, divs_: 100] := DensityPlot[
  y, {x, 0, 0.2}, {y, min, max},
  PlotPoints -> {2, divs},
  ColorFunction -> colorFunction,
  AspectRatio -> 10,
  PlotRangePadding -> 0,
  MaxRecursion -> 0,
  FrameTicks -> {None, Automatic},
  FrameLabel -> {"", "Z"}];

MyData = Import["DataFileXYZ.dat", "Table"];

MyColorBar :=  Show[colorbar[
   {Min[Transpose[MyData][[3]]], Max[Transpose[MyData][[3]]]},
   "Temperature"]];

MyPlot :=  ListDensityPlot[
  MyData, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{height}, 
  ColorData["Temperature"][height]], 
  FrameLabel -> {"X", "Y"}]

Row[Show[#, ImageSize -> {Automatic, 600}] & /@ {MyPlot, MyColorBar}]
```

Data file I used is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/y1oqx8kv5o39ter/DataFileXYZ.txt?dl=0

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Please provide a data sample.

Comment: Have you tried different colour schemes?  Maybe "Rainbow" or "BrightBands".  Have you tried a gamma correction instead of a log?  Have you tried a `ListContourPlot` and specify the contours you want?

Comment: Hi @wxffles, different color schemes have the same problems. No sure how to apply a gamma correction in this case.  And finally, I am already using ListContourPlot for other specific values, and I can't over crowd the plot with contours to show details in the blue part of the densityplot.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you could add a gamma correction:

```
Clear[gamma];
gamma[x_?NumericQ, ɣ_] := x^(1/ɣ);

MyScale = gamma[#, 4] &;
```

In your colorbar you plot `MyScale@y` and in the plot ColorFunction you have `MyScale@height`, and then:

[image: 1]